# How to change background image of lock screen?

Tags: windows-8, images, standby

Where can I change the background image from the Windows 8 lockscreen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Goto `Settings` (move the mouse to the upper or lower right corner of the screen)
2. Click `Change PC Settings`
3. Click `Personalize`
4. Click on the `Browse` button on the right, under the picture of your lockscreen
5. Choose your picture and click `Choose picture`

[Step-by-Step Tutorial with pictures](http://www.intowindows.com/change-windows-8-logon-screen-lock-screen/)

Comment: Link only answers are bad answers. If the page changes or gets deleted your answer will be useless. Please summarise the page here.

Answer (score 0):

In the Apptivate contest being sponsored by Microsoft and Stackoverflow, a user has submitted an app for changing the lockscreen image via Bing. It's a really cool app and you might want to take a look at it. And yes, it's already on the Windows Store.

http://apptivate.ms/apps/4/bing-my-lockscreen